How to integrate a Android SDK with bare expo react native app?
I am trying to integrate OLA maps in my expo app but not able to find the correct steps. I have searched everywhere but since this is new lib there isn't much online.
Reference Doc : https://maps.olakrutrim.com/docs/sdks/map-sdks/android
